# Как поменять кастомный виджет?

Tags: php, wordpress

В теме используется виджет, созданный примерно так:

```
class LaStudio_Swatch_Widget extends WC_Widget{
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
       ...
       $found = $this->layered_nav_list( $terms, $taxonomy, $query_type );
    }

    protected function layered_nav_list( $terms, $taxonomy, $query_type ) {
        ....
    }
}
```

мне нужно заменить метод `layered_nav_list`.
Как это правильно сделать, не меняя код виджета `LaStudio_Swatch_Widget`?
т.е. какие хуки вызывать и как переопределить?

**P.S.**
это не сработало:

```
function wpb_load_widget() {
    if(class_exists('LaStudio_Swatch_Widget')){
        class Custom_LaStudio_Swatch_Widget extends LaStudio_Swatch_Widget{
            protected function layered_nav_list( $terms, $taxonomy, $query_type ) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    register_widget( 'Custom_LaStudio_Swatch_Widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget' );
```

Comment: уже работает, нужно было подобрать приоритетность `add_action`

Comment: Вот я и так подумал. Ход мыслей-то правильный. Надо было только отменить родительский виджет.

Comment: @KAGG Design, т.е. в вышеприведённом коде нужно сначала отменить виджет? `unregister_widget( 'LaStudio_Swatch_Widget' );`

Comment: Ну да, я не совсем понимаю, как они оба будут работать одновременно. Логично отменить исходный и запустить свой, который дочерний класс от исходного, и подменить protected метод. Т.е. дальше всё правильно сделано.